# Installed Animated css via npm now what?

Tags: css, npm, animate.css

Hello guys I am new to node.
I have installed **animate.css** via npm and tested it on a HTML `<div>` element it created like usual the JSON package file. The code e.g.:

```html
<h1 class="animate__animated animate__pulse">Animate box</h1>
<div class="animate-box animate__animated animate__pulse"></div>
```

Nothing is moving? Do I have to link it in head anyways?

Thank you for the noob question :D

Comment: You must to provide more details regarding your code, how do you add this dependency?

Comment: Are you `importing` the dependency into any of the pages you're trying to use them on?

Answer (score 0):

For usage with the `npm` package, you'll need a full asset build stack which compiles `animate.css` into whatever CSS bundle your page already uses.

Because you said you are new to code, I highly suggest you stay away from this topic for a while. Instead, simply make use of the other suggested way, including `animate.css` via a content delivery network (CDN):

```html
<head>
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"
  />
</head>
```

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for your reply. It is true i am new, but i can read instructions. 
It says here [https://animate.style/] : Install with npm: _then the code_
**or add it directly to your webpage using a CDN:** 
So would you be confused as a beginner when reading this?

Comment: I would, but the documentation really cannot give you all the details. There's soooooooo much to it.

Comment: Yeah, for sure. But hey, I am learning. Trying things out. Cheers. :)